# ethernet not working on new Lubuntu 12.10 installation

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, ethernet

The title says it all, I freshly installed Lubuntu 12.10 and it isn't able to connect to the intranet and/or internet. Actually, it is working randomly, if I restart the computer 2-3 times, it might work 1 time.

But it's now booted up and not working. Here's what I got from lspci, lsmod and ifconfig:

```
daniel@server:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82Q963/Q965 Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev f2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HB/HR (ICH8/R) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) 4 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HR/HO/HH (ICH8R/DO/DH) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
0a:0c.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7131/SAA7133/SAA7135 Video Broadcast Decoder (rev d1)


daniel@server:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
saa7134_alsa           18052  0 
rc_msi_tvanywhere_plus    12490  0 
ir_kbd_i2c             12983  0 
rfcomm                 37276  0 
bnep                   17707  2 
parport_pc             31968  0 
bluetooth             183228  10 rfcomm,bnep
ppdev                  12817  0 
tda827x                17778  1 
coretemp               13168  0 
kvm_intel             126745  0 
kvm                   357806  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_analog    75059  1 
tda8290                22061  1 
tuner                  26797  1 
snd_hda_intel          32515  1 
snd_hda_codec         111547  2 snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_intel
microcode              18209  0 
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80163  3 saa7134_alsa,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25382  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51255  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
psmouse                84843  0 
saa7134               157506  1 saa7134_alsa
tpm_tis                18208  0 
rc_core                21266  4 rc_msi_tvanywhere_plus,ir_kbd_i2c,saa7134
videobuf_dma_sg        18714  2 saa7134_alsa,saa7134
videobuf_core          25097  2 saa7134,videobuf_dma_sg
v4l2_common            15767  2 tuner,saa7134
videodev               95841  3 tuner,saa7134,v4l2_common
serio_raw              13031  0 
tveeprom               17009  1 saa7134
snd_timer              24411  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
lpc_ich                16925  0 
snd                    61991  12 saa7134_alsa,snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
i915                  457161  2 
mac_hid                13037  0 
drm_kms_helper         45271  1 i915
drm                   230463  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
video                  18847  1 i915
soundcore              14599  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14036  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40753  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
hid_generic            12445  0 
usbhid                 41702  0 
hid                    82142  2 hid_generic,usbhid
floppy                 55444  0 
tg3                   130448  0 


daniel@server:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:6b:51:4a:b7  
          adr inet6: fe80::21a:6bff:fe51:4ab7/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:4 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:439 (439.0 B) Octets transmis:9972 (9.9 KB)
          Interruption:16 

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:4952 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
          Octets reçus:377832 (377.8 KB) Octets transmis:377832 (377.8 KB)
```

The computer is a old Lenovo/IBM M52 Thinkcentre with an Intel E6400 dual core, 2GB of RAM and a GMA950 IGP chip. What's wrong with the ethernet?

Please note that Windows 7 and Windows XP are also installed on the same 40GB SSD and booting correctly from GRUB, both work correctly with my ethernet card. On my switch, I can see the light is green on this IBM computer's port whether I'm in XP, 7 or Lubuntu OS.

Please note that I'm not a linux guru or whatsoever, I consider myself a noob and I'm trying to do my best to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had assigned a fixed internal IP address on the DHCP server to that computer. If I remove the assignation, it works fine. Because I don't really need the fixed IP address, I assume my problem is now solved.